# Row is listed twice in simple query

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

One row is Repeated twice and I can't seem to figure out why. I tried using Group by but couldn't figure that out either lol. Using Left outer Join, to list suppliers who have a discounted product, in the Northwind Database

```
Select *
From Suppliers s
  Left Outer Join products p
   On s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
Where p.Discontinued = 1
```

Comment: Show us some example data, raw, and after query, and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

You have two discontinued products for a supplier, and a row is created for each row in `products` that matches the join condition and the `Discontinued = 1` predicate. You want something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM Suppliers s 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM Products p 
                WHERE p.SupplierID = s.SupplierID 
                  AND p.Discontinued = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two rows in one of those tables. You can determine which by querying both tables by themselves on that supplierId.

Now, to your query, by putting p.discontinued in the where, that join effectively becomes an inner join, so you should either flip it to an inner join or move that condition to the join.

To get suppliers with discontinued products, you can do this:

```
Select * from supplier where supplierId in (
   select supplierId from products 
   where discontinued =1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is clearly a supplier that has multiple discontinued products.

If you want suppliers with at least one discounted product, then use `exists`:

```
select s.*
from suppliers s
where exists (select 1 
              from products p
              where p.supplierid = s.supplierid and
                    p.Discontinued = 1
             );
```

If you want the list of suppliers with the number of discontinued products, use `join`:

```
select s.*, p.num_discontinued
from supplier s join
     (select p.supplierid, count(*) as num_discontinued
      from products
      where p.Discontinued = 1
      group by p.supplierid
     ) p
     on p.SupplierID = s.SupplierID ;
```

If you want the list of products that are discontinued with their suppliers, than use your query but change the `left join` to an `inner join`.  An outer join is not necessary.